# htaccess for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I need a .htaccess file:
the file will rewrite rule for:

**xyz.sitename.com**
will be rewritten as:
**sitename.com/index.php/a/b/xyz**

**xyz.sitename.com/m/n/o**
will be rewritten as:
**sitename.com/index.php/m/n/o/xyz**

**sitename.com/m/n/o**
will be rewritten as:
**sitename.com/index.php/m/n/o**

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+).sitename.com/ sitename.com/index.php/a/b/$1
RewriteRule (.+).sitename.com/(.+) sitename.com/$2/$1
```

See [.htaccess trips and tips](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php).

Comment: xyz.sitename.com will be rewritten as: sitename.com/index.php/a/b/xyz

xyz.sitename.com/m/n/o will be rewritten as: sitename.com/index.php/m/n/o/xyz

sitename.com/m/n/o will be rewritten as: sitename.com/index.php/m/n/o


please, solve this, and help me

Comment: mod_rewrite only works on the path after the domain name http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html - you'd need a lot of RewriteConds to deal with this...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [OR]
RewriteCond /%{HTTP_HOST} ^(/[^\.]+)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php/$0%1
```

Although, as I've [mentioned in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227794/unable-to-allow-these-characters-in-url/3228998#3228998), trying to create `PATH_INFO` with `mod_rewrite` seems to be a little problematic. You might have better luck, but take the alternatives of writing the path to a query string or using `$_SERVER` variables to get this information into consideration.