# %2F in URL breaks and does not reference to the .php file required

Tags: php, apache, url

I need to pass / as a variable as part of a URL.

My structure looks like this: 
www.domain.com/listings/page-1/city-Burnaby+South/type-Townhome/bedroom-2/bathroom-2

In this case, it ultimately boils down to listings.php and everything else beyond it becomes parameters taht my PHP script parses through using the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] var.

However when one of hte variables becomes "Apartment/Condo" and the / becomes %2F via urlencode() in PHP when the URL is generated, the whole thing chokes and I get a "Not Found" error.

How do I pass the / without breaking the URL? What am I missing? I thought the whole point of these urlencode() characters (%2F, %20 etc.) were there to escape these issues.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Urls with *%2f* `/` or *%5c* `\` return a *404* from `Apache` for security purposes.

You may modify Apache config to enable `AllowEncodedSlashes On` or `NoDecode`.  Keep in mind that this may introduce unintended security issues, which this "feature" is designed to mitigate.

Apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Solved:

- [Receive an HTTP 400 error if %2F is part of the GET URL in JBOSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069002/http-400-if-2f-part-of-get-url-in-jboss)

This one got me too -- thanks for the question

Comment: That explains. Thanks so much.

Answer (score -4):

You can equally just do [`urldecode();`](http://de.php.net/urldecode)

Comment: The URL is passed and decoded using urldecode(). My issue is that it doesn't even render to the PHP page - it returns a 404 as soon as there is a %2F included in the request somewhere.

Comment: The request fails to get to invoking PHP, so no this is not a solution