# Changing "/" to "%2f" in URL doesn't work

Tags: url, percent-encoding

I have an orchard site and have the following problem:

If I use the URL: http://asiahotelct.com/tours/ct---chau-%C4%91oc---ha-tien-3n2%C4%91, it's okay. But when I change url the `/` to `%2f` (like so: [http://asiahotelct.com/tours%2fct---chau-%C4%91oc---ha-tien-3n2%C4%91](http://asiahotelct.com/tours/ct---chau-%C4%91oc---ha-tien-3n2%C4%91)), it no longer works.

Why can `/` not be replaced by `%2f`?

Comment: `/` is a path separator. `%2f` is a character that will eventually convert into a `/`, but is **NOT** a path separator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [%2F in URL breaks and does not reference to the .php file required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206835/2f-in-url-breaks-and-does-not-reference-to-the-php-file-required)

Comment: The subtle difference between `%2F` versus `/` was the architect of all my pain while I was trying to make my curl bash script work for `gitlab.com` REST API.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but how to get it work: Use a parameter:  http://asiahotelct.com/tours?id=ct---chau-%C4%91oc---ha-tien-3n2%C4%91 will work.

Answer (score 27):

Any **url** is a kind of complete address to some resource(file) in network. But according to the rules of *how it must be actually* (to *work* as you expect), its expected that a few characters must have some specific meaning; just like in this case: "/" means a separator that separates the individual *elements* of your address(url).

But in case you need such specific characters to be a part of any such *element* of address(url), we must encode it. [List of codes](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)

> URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted
>   over the Internet.
>   - w3Schools

So, **"/"** is actually a seperator, but **"%2f"** becomes an ordinary character that simply represents "/" character in element of your url.