# AngularJs ngRoutes not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ngroute, hashbang

I add this link tag `<a href="#/pendingJobs">` And in Js wrote this type of when function

```
.when("/pendingJobs", {
    templateUrl : 'jobsPending.php',
    controller : 'appCtrl'
})
```

But when i click on link it create a url like that `/#%2FpendingJobs`due to this linking problem `.when("/pendingJobs"` is not working..

Comment: did you enabled  `html5mode`?

Comment: works fine here http://run.plnkr.co/HaAi55Ovu9yXdiEV/#/

Comment: That has to work, check ur code may be for any spaces or syntax issue check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13210859/2878777)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default value of the prefix is changed to  to '!'.

I don't know which angular version you are using.

But it should work with this changes.Change `hashPrefix` to `''`

```
.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
})
```

More here [`https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52)