# Apache rewrite rule query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to write a Rewriterule which takes a domain from a URL of the format

```
https://www.example.com/sample?TARGET=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fexample%2Fhelp%3Fparam%3D1.
```

If the `TARGET` parameter is present I need to redirect the user to the value inside the `TARGET` query parameter. My rewrite rule is below:

```
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING}  TARGET=([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %1? [R=302,L]
```

This does not work because of two problems:

1. `%1?` in the rewrite rule causes the rewrite to append the value of the TARGET query string to the existing domain.
2. The value of `%1` only contains `https` rather than `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fexample%2Fhelp%3Fparam%3D1`.

I understand that this might not be the best way to go ahead with this, and I am open to suggestions.

Comment: [`%2F` in URLs is considered a security risk and is not allowed by default by Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206835/2f-in-url-breaks-and-does-not-reference-to-the-php-file-required)

Comment: But if you have decoded URL e.g. `https://www.example.com/sample?TARGET=https://www.example.com/example/help?param=1` then rule can redirect.

Comment: I tried with both.. The value after the dot gets cut off.. Leaving only https in it

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^TARGET=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [NE,R=302,L]
```

Important to use `.+` in regex to be able to capture all characters of the URL specified in `TARGET` parameter.

This will redirect:

`http://yourdomain.com/?TARGET=https://www.example.com/example/help?param=1` to

`https://www.example.com/example/help?param=1`