# Show customized error page for forbidden request

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server, apache2.4

I am trying to validate the following URL's

http://www.domain.com/foldername/%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2fetc%2fpasswd

But this was showing as 403 forbidden of default server error instead of customized error page

My `.htaccess` file configuration is

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

**For Example,**

For this URL we got the customized error page https://stackoverflow.com/welcome

[image]

But If we execute this URL we got the default error page of server

https://stackoverflow.com/%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2fetc%2fpasswd

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google detects well https://www.google.co.in/%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2fetc%2fpasswd

Comment: `%2F` isn't allowed in Apache URLs

Comment: how to handle this error

Comment: facebook handles well https://www.facebook.com/%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2fetc%2fpasswd

Comment: Your web server is different and FB is different. [see this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206835/2f-in-url-breaks-and-does-not-reference-to-the-php-file-required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to your httpd.conf

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

And restart apache.

After that apache should treat your url as valid. ( so 404 page should be shown )