# Apache .htaccess redirection issue

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I've recently come across a very strange problem with my Apache instance that I can't seem to find an answer to, I could be looking in the wrong places.

For my website I always run all requests through my `index.php` (All other content JS/CSS/PNG goes through a separate CDN), so I use my `.htaccess` to redirect *all* requests like so

```
SetEnv SERVER_ADMIN admin@example.com
SetEnv PHPRC /home/user
ServerSignature email
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage en-US

# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options All -Indexes

# Do not redirect these directories
RewriteRule sitemap.xml - [L]
RewriteRule robots.txt - [L]

# Redirect to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

I read the path provided from the `$_SERVER` variable, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

I recently came across an issue that when I attempt to send any `REQUEST_METHOD` to my webserver that the request becomes a `GET`, but ***only if*** my URL contains an escaped `/` (`%2F`). While debugging this issue I `print_r`'d my `$_SERVER` variable to find the following:

#### A `DELETE` request to `example.com/%2F`

(Just a note that this isn't a trailing `/` issue, the issue happens no matter where it is in the URL, and I'm not unescaping it in my code)

```
{
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD": "DELETE",
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS": "200",
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_SERVER_ADMIN": "admin@example.com",
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHPRC": "/home/user",
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_HTTPS": "on",
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI": "www.example.com",
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS": "200",
  "REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": "",
  "REDIRECT_SERVER_ADMIN": "admin@example.com",
  "REDIRECT_PHPRC": "/home/user",
  "REDIRECT_HTTPS": "on",
  "REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI": "www.example.com",
  "REDIRECT_STATUS": "200",
  "HTTPS": "on",
  "SSL_TLS_SNI": "www.example.com",
  "HTTP_HOST": "www.example.com",
  "REQUEST_METHOD": "GET",
  "REQUEST_URI": "/%2F",
  "SCRIPT_NAME": "/index.php"
}
```

#### A `DELETE` request to `example.com`

```
{
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_SERVER_ADMIN": "admin@example.com",
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHPRC": "/home/user",
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_HTTPS": "on",
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI": "www.example.com",
  "REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS": "200",
  "REDIRECT_SERVER_ADMIN": "admin@example.com",
  "REDIRECT_PHPRC": "/home/user",
  "REDIRECT_HTTPS": "on",
  "REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI": "www.example.com",
  "REDIRECT_STATUS": "200",
  "HTTPS": "on",
  "SSL_TLS_SNI": "www.example.com",
  "HTTP_HOST": "www.example.com",
  "REQUEST_METHOD": "DELETE",
  "REQUEST_URI": "/",
  "SCRIPT_NAME": "/index.php"
}
```

I've yet to find out why this escaped symbol is causing an additional redirect, and as to why it's changing the request method. [I came across one suggestion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data) to replace my `RewriteRule [L]` to a `RewriteRule [P]` to proxy the request, but that only caused errors. The [RewriteRule Flags documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) states that the proxy rule should be used with an external URL.

Any suggestions and/or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem with some further digging through StackOverflow.

First idea was just to read the `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REDIRECT_METHOD']` but I would **NOT** recommend doing this, as it turns out that Apache was also forcing a `404` response code during this redirect, meaning any URLs with an encoding `%2F` were returning as *Not Found* (Even with my page content showing up).

Answer came from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12993237/11466130).

## Solution:

```
# Set this rule in .htaccess/httpd.conf
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```