# how can I pass parameter with slash as the PathParam in rest API

Tags: rest, tomcat, urlencode, urldecode, path-parameter

I build a rest API like www.example.com/checking/{id} and it works well. But when I passed in a id with slash, like abc/123, then the API path becomes the www.example.com/checking/abc/123 which actually breaks the path.

I can use the encoded URL id, like abc/123 encoded as abc%2F123, but it seems like when I use it to hit my API, it is hanging there, I can not find something in the log.

Is there any suggestion so that I can do this ? Is it a tomcat configuration issue or coding issue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have to use regex in your path, like this:

```
@Path("{name:.+}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the solutions posted in this tread and solve the problem.

[Receive an HTTP 400 error if %2F is part of the GET URL in JBOSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069002/receive-an-http-400-error-if-2f-is-part-of-the-get-url-in-jboss)