# How to pass '/' character in the GET request?

Tags: java, spring-restcontroller

I have an api :

```
http://localhost:8080/mylocalserver/#/reports/{parameter1}/{parameter2}
```

now the first parameter is parameter1 = "12345/EF"
and the second parameter is parameter2 = "Text"

I am using Spring Rest Controller for creating the api.
When the request is made with the following above parameters it shows 
`Request Not Found` error.

I have tried encoding and decoding the Parameters using `URLEncoder.encode` and also with `UriUtils.encode(param, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())` but still getting the same error.

Below is the code which I tried.

Suppose I got two variables from User Input 
`parameter1` and `parameter2`

Now I create a URL with the following parameter

```
private void createApi(String parameter1, String parameter2) {
    try {
      String uri = " http://localhost:8080/mylocalserver/#/reports/"+encode(parameter1)+"/"+encode(parameter2)+" ";

      ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes =
          (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
      HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
      HttpServletResponse response = requestAttributes.getResponse();
      request.getRequestDispatcher(uri).forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
```

And My encode method is :

```
public String encode(String param) {
    try {
     UriUtils.encode(param, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return param;
  }
```

Note : I am using Tomcat 8.5

Comment: Please have a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables

Comment: Does it work if you manually escape the slash with `12345%2FEF`?

Comment: @assylias the request is purely dependent on the user as he can enter any value in the variable therefore I cannot manually replace the values.Therefore I tried encoding the parameters but it didn't work.

Comment: Nice explanation and possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069002/receive-an-http-400-error-if-2f-is-part-of-the-get-url-in-jboss

Comment: @sven.kwiotek the given questions only handle a specific case of this problem.

Comment: @swetanshkumar Understood, but does it work if you do it manually? If it does then you know the problem is with the encoding of the URL. If it doesn't then the problem may be with your web service.

Comment: I need to add a global method for handling these types

Comment: @assylias it works when I do it manually but I have to make a dedicated method for handling it in my all apis.

Comment: You should post the code that is failing, maybe we would find what's wrong with that. Otherwise we can just write theories. There will likely be some silly mistake, that is usually the case :)

Comment: @swetanshkumar The thing is that `URLEncoder.encode("12345/EF", UTF_8.toString())` does return `12345%2FEF` as expected - and you say that when you pass that string manually it works fine. So it's not clear what is going on. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @assylias edited the question with my code

Comment: *the request is purely dependent on the user*: then it doesn't identify a resource, and should rather be a query parameter than a path variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your encode method is broken:

There is missing `return` statement.

```
public String encode(String param) {
    try {
        //missing return at this line in your code
        return UriUtils.encode(param, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return param;
  }
```

And BTW you can make this method static.

Comment: It would probably clearer if you fixed the error instead of just pointing it out.

Comment: But that fix I had done already as it was typing mistake by me. Please provide a better method that this one

Comment: Then show your real code - this answer solves the problem you describe in your question (except maybe the error handling but which returns the original string if an error is found)...