# Apache URL Rewriting misbehaving

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, urlencode, httpd.conf

I have the setup below; a very simple URL rewrite setup with a test setup

```
// ----- test.php -----
<?php

phpinfo();
// ----- test.php -----
```

The config for test.local is as below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test
        ServerAlias test.*
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/test/">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule .* test.php/$0 [R,NE]
</Directory>
```

Now if I make a request `GET http://test.local/my-path-info` the default `phpinfo()` page appears as expected, if I add slash in the path info, that works too. But if I add an encoded forward slash `%2F` into the URL (example `GET http://test.local/my-path-info%2fsomething-else`), it comes up as `404 Not found`. Basically it doesn't get to the php file.

Any idea why this is happening, and how to get around it?

The setup is on Apache 2.2.13, PHP 5.3.8 on Linux (Centos 5.x).

NOTE: What I am trying to do here is to add a forward slash into one of the path-info components, such that it doesn't get interpreted by the router logic in an MVC framework. Without encoding it, the router cannot differentiate between a slash that is a path separator and the one that is part of a path component.

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219/urlencoded-forward-slash-is-breaking-url

Comment: Wouldn't you be wanting your <Directory> directives in your <Virtualhost> body for this to not become an Apache global directive?

Comment: Thanks @Skittles you are absolutely right; but at the same time it is the right config, specific to my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the apache version that doesnt support `NoDecode` as an option for `AllowEncodedSlashes`, I ended up using the below combination. I also had to double url-encode the request URI. Not ideal but works for me for the moment.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test
        ServerAlias test.*
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
        AllowEncodedSlashes On
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/test/">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        # Option B below was the key!
        RewriteRule .* test.php/$0 [R,NE,B]
</Directory>
```