# Encoded slash (%2F) with Spring RequestMapping path param gives HTTP 400

Tags: spring, rest, glassfish, glassfish-3, spring-3

*This is not a duplicate [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219), because it is Spring specific.  Whoever added that (3 years after the fact!) didn't bother to read the question or comment thread to see what the real answer was.  The accepted answer isn't quite the answer, but the author of the answer never came back and edited it like I asked.*

Given the restful method below, Spring 3.1 gives a 400 error with "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()." when the `token` parameter contains a URL encoded slash (%2F), for example "https://somewhere.com/ws/stuff/lookup/resourceId/287559/token/R4o6lI%2FbBx43/userName/jim"  Without the %2F everything works fine.  A 3rd party is already calling this service (of course!) so I can't change what they send, in the short term at least.  Any ideas on how to work around this on the server side?

This problem is described very well here https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8662 though that issue is related to UriTemplate which I am not using that I can tell.

```
@RequestMapping("/ws/stuff/**")
@Controller
public class StuffController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/ws/stuff/lookup/resourceId/{resourceId}/token/{token}/userName/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody
   String provisionResource(@PathVariable("resourceId") String resourceId, @PathVariable("token") String token, @PathVariable("userName") String userName, ModelMap modelMap,
         HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
      return handle(resourceId, userName, request, token, modelMap);
   }
}
```

Note: This is on Glassfish 3.1.2, and at first it was Grizzly/Glassfish not accepting the slash, but

`-Dcom.sun.grizzly.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true`

fixed that.

`asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.http.encoded-slash-enabled=true`

didn't seem to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urlencoded Forward slash is breaking URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219/urlencoded-forward-slash-is-breaking-url)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This could be your answer: [urlencoded Forward slash is breaking URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219/urlencoded-forward-slash-is-breaking-url)

I would suggest not putting that in the path, move it to a request param instead.

**Work around:**

You could change the RequestMapping to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ws/stuff/lookup/resourceId/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and then parse the path variables manually from the request object.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the 3rd party's code any time soon.  I'm not using Apache, as stated, though Grizzly does have a similar configuration, which I have already turned off, as stated.  This problem is now happening at the Spring level.

Comment: In that case, you could change the RequestMapping to   @RequestMapping(value = "/ws/stuff/lookup/resourceId/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
and then parse the path variables manually from the request object.

Comment: Make that an answer, Lithium, and I'll accept it :-)  That is a simple and reasonable way to get this working.  I say that, so that people coming and finding this later will quickly see a good solution.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Even with "/**" I always get 400, if %2F appears in the path.

Comment: Simple fix, but this should really be supported. Spring shouldn't decode the path _before_ it find the relevant mapping.

Comment: In REST, path and query params have slightly different implications. A path param is part of the resource name, and a query param is generally a filter argument passed to a named resource. There's no technical reason resource names can't include a slash character - that's exactly what URL encoding is for.

Answer (score 25):

for spring-boot, the following did the trick

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setUrlDecode(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }

}
```

Comment: It helped with UrlPathHelperFixed which is mentioned above. Because otherwise fails with double slashes. And it parses whole path parameter correctly and doesn't need to hack from the request.

Comment: I've tried this with ``UrlPathHelperFixed`` from https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11101 but it didn't work

Comment: ...using Spring Boot ``1.5.9-RELEASE``

Comment: You'll also need this with Spring Boot 2 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48636757/636849 In order to avoid errors such as `RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "%2F"`

Answer (score 17):

### 2019 Update for Spring Boot 2+ / Spring (Security) 5+ / Java 8+:

As my edit to [iamiddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37601103/1326662) was rejected I want to also provide the complete solution for Spring Boot 2 + as an separate answer.

The `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated with Spring5 / Java8 and can be replaced directly with the Interface `WebMvcConfigurer` ending up with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setUrlDecode(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```

Plus you also need to configure Spring's `(Strict)HttpFirewall` to avoid the blocking of encoded slashes with the error message `The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "%2F"`

```
@Bean
public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);    
    return firewall;
}
```

Spring Boot will use the above `HttpFirewall` Bean when available - otherwise it might be necessary to configure the `WebSecurity` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48636757/1326662):

Comment: 2 things: firstly the firewall part is optional, if you do not use the spring-security of course and second - if you use jetty, just override the configurePathMatch method. I have not found anyting about jetty only that it should work unlike in tomcat, but that was not the case and I had to fix it.

Comment: according to [Tomcat 9 docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/systemprops.html) the property `UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH` is going to be deprecated.
So it could be

   `@Bean`
    `public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tomcatCustomizer() {`
        `return factory -> factory.addConnectorCustomizers(`
                `connector -> connector.setEncodedSolidusHandling(PASS_THROUGH.getValue()));`
    `}`

Comment: @leonid for me it worked with DECODE
`connector ->  connector.setEncodedSolidusHandling(EncodedSolidusHandling.DECODE.getValue()));`

Comment: I've applied the solution it works over postman, but started to get CORS error when testing it over browser.

Comment: CORS error doesn't sound like it is related to "encoded slashes"?

Comment: I'hev fixed it. Have you also tried to test this function via Springboot test?

Comment: Honestly I can't remember - that was 3,5 years ago...

Answer (score 9):

For spring boot application this worked for me..

**Version 1** 
Add

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```

to your *application.properties* file

**Version 2**
run your spring boot application like this.

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
    SpringApplication.run this, args
}
```

Version 3 or run your java application with 
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true

This fixed %2F encoded slash path variable for me.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a fix for Spring 3.2.4 (should work for other versions as well). One must overwrite the default UrlPathHelper

```java
    public class UrlPathHelperFixed extends UrlPathHelper {

        public UrlPathHelperFixed() {
            super.setUrlDecode(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void setUrlDecode(boolean urlDecode) {
            if (urlDecode) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Handler [" + UrlPathHelperFixed.class.getName() + "] does not support URL decoding.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getServletPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return getOriginatingServletPath(request);
        }

        @Override
        public String getOriginatingServletPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
        }
    }
```

And inject it to the Mapping Handler:

```xml
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="-1"></property>
        <property name="urlPathHelper">
            <bean class="com.yoochoose.frontend.spring.UrlPathHelperFixed"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

After a day of hard works it works now for me :-)

It was suggested to Spring team as https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11101

Comment: Nice. It's fixed in Spring 3.2.8 according to the tkt.

Comment: Using this fix still solves the issue for Spring 4.3.8; just setting urlDecode=false as suggested elsewhere doesn't seem to work correctly in all cases (although it does seem to work fine for some).

Answer (score 7):

**Spring Boot 3.x / Tomcat 10.x solution**

Thanks to the comments from @leonid and @Edu, I managed to fix it for Tomcat 10.x, which [removed](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/changelog.html) the support for `UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH`. They mention in the release notes:

> Replace the system property org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH with the Connector attribute encodedSolidusHandling that adds an additional option to pass the %2f sequence through to the application without decoding it in addition to rejecting such sequences and decoding such sequences. (markt)

The Spring-equivalent of this is exactly what [leonid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5841911/leonid) and [Edu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253946/edu) pointed out:

```java
    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tomcatCustomizer() {
        log.info("Configuring Tomcat to allow encoded slashes.");
        return factory -> factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> connector.setEncodedSolidusHandling(
                EncodedSolidusHandling.DECODE.getValue()));
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I have found this solution which is working for me;

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
```

just before 
springApplication.run(args);

and add below code in Application class

```
 @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setUrlDecode(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We just ran into this issue at my office, we did what was suggestion above from what [Solubris said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13488354/712849) where you put it in a query param. The only additional requirement is that the data could have an '&' as well, which would mess up the query param. All we had to do is encode the text before it is sent in the URL and even '&' were filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer would be to encode `"/"` twice, which would produce `"%252F"`. 
In your mapped endpoint, Spring will decode it back to `"%2F"`. All you need more is to decode it one more time using something like this:

`URLDecoder.decode(encoded_URL, "UTF-8");`

Comment: that would have been clever but %25 is recognized as malicious as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid parsing the variables manually I did the following:

1. Add the following before executing any other code:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
```

2. **And** in the controller, add 2 variables instead one, for example:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/devices-by-name/device={deviceId}/restconf/data/ietf-interfaces:interfaces-state/interface={dpuIdPrefix}/{dpuIdSuffix}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getInterfaceState(@PathVariable(value = "deviceId") String deviceId,
                                                    @PathVariable(value = "dpuIdPrefix") String dpuIdPrefix,
                                                    @PathVariable(value = "dpuIdSuffix") String dpuIdSuffix) {
        String dpuId = dpuIdPrefix + "/" + dpuIdSuffix;
```

And with that I can retrieve the following:

```
curl -s -X GET http://localhost:9090/api/devices-by-name/device=ZNSDX16DPU03/restconf/data/ietf-interfaces:interfaces-state/interface=gfast%200%2F14
```

If the slash is optional, then you might need to configure two different request mappings.

Answer (score 0):

For **Spring Boot 3+** which uses **Tomcat 10+** (where `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH` doesn't work anymore) it needs to configure:

```
@Component
public class EmbeddedTomcatServerCustomizer
    implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.getTomcatConnectorCustomizers().add(connector -> connector.setEncodedSolidusHandling("decode"));
    }
}
```

and web config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setUrlDecode(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        return firewall;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following resolved the BACK_SLASH issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

But, same functionality could be done via application.yml.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH: true
```

This setting doesn't work. I did not find a way for that, and still looking at it.

Comment: To clarify, a "back slash" means the one that starts at the upper left and crosses down to the lower right, and a slash goes the other way.  URLs have a SLASH (`https://www.stackoverflow.com`), Windows paths have a BACK_SLASH (`c:\windows`) for example.