# Encoded Forward Slash %2F gets decoded and break URL mapping in Spring Rest Data with Jetty

Tags: spring, rest, url, spring-rest, slash

I am using Spring Rest Data and I have entities with IDs containing forward slashes "/".
My person ID is for example abcd/efg and this URL returns error 400.

```
http://localhost:8085/myapp/person/abcd/efg
```

If I try to encode the slash (%2F), I get the same problem.

```
http://localhost:8085/myapp/person/abcd%2Fefg
```

How do I request this entity with an slash in the ID?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encoded slash (%2F) with Spring RequestMapping path param gives HTTP 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482020/encoded-slash-2f-with-spring-requestmapping-path-param-gives-http-400)