# Spring requestMapping takes %2f in requestParam as slash (/)

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

Tokens are generated from a third party service.
Sometimes these tokens include `%2F` like `0Tqn66huZhfX%2Fft7nPnCj1Id`

I am writing a wrapper for this service and using spring rest.

When i send token with `%2F` in it to spring controller as `@RequestParam` it treats `%2F` as `/` character,

`0Tqn66huZhfX%2Fft7nPnCj1Id` becomes `0Tqn66huZhfX/ft7nPnCj1Id`.

I must send this token to another server like below.

http://example.com/{token}/{otherVariable}

As spring gets `%2F` as `/`, it breaks the url format.

What can i do to get the token value with `%2F` without it being converted to `/`?

Comment: URL encode your token before using it to send a request.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482020/encoded-slash-2f-with-spring-requestmapping-path-param-gives-http-400

Answer (score -1):

Browsers will encode the URL , based on character set used. we can prevent by using JS...etc,.

> solution:
>   before sending request encode that url using:

`in JS: use encodeURI(url)`,
This function encodes special characters, `except: , / ? : @ & = + $ #`
for decode use: `decodeURI(url)`

Comment: ; , / ? : @ & = + $ are reserved characters in encodeURI and will not be encoded, as stated in the function's documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI