# Jasypt encryption - remove slash when encrypting

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jasypt

I'm currently using [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) as my encryption tool, the problem is once a word has been encrypted, it produces '/', i want to avoid slashes in my encryptions. the reason for that is i'm using it in my url.

so for example jasypt produces this encrypted text:

```
String encryptedText = "/O0sJjPUFgRGfND1TpHrkbyCalgY/rSpE8nhJ/wYjYY=";
```

I will be appending this in my link..

example of that is:

```
String.format("%s%s", "youtube.com/videos/", encryptedText);
```

this will redirect me to another link, so instead of going to videos section, it will go to **/O0sJjPUFgRGfND1TpHrkbyCalgY**

here's my code:

```
public class EncryptionUtil {
    public static final String ENCRYPTION_KEY = "test-encryption";
    private static final String EMPTY_KEY_OR_TEXT = "Decryption key and text must not be empty.";

    public static String decrypt(final String encryptedText) {
        if (StringUtils.isAnyBlank(encryptedText)) {
            throw new ApiErrorException(EMPTY_KEY_OR_TEXT);
        }
        try {
            final char[] keyCharArray = ENCRYPTION_KEY.toCharArray();
            final BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
            textEncryptor.setPasswordCharArray(keyCharArray);

            return textEncryptor.decrypt(encryptedText);
        } catch (EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException e) {
            throw new ApiErrorException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(final String plaintext) {
        if (StringUtils.isAnyBlank(plaintext)) {
            throw new ApiErrorException(EMPTY_KEY_OR_TEXT);
        }
        final char[] keyCharArray = ENCRYPTION_KEY.toCharArray();
        final BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
        textEncryptor.setPasswordCharArray(keyCharArray);

        return textEncryptor.encrypt(plaintext);
    }
}
```

Here's my spring controller:

```
@GetMapping("/profile/client-users/{userId}")
    public ModelAndView getAccountAccess(
        @PathVariable String userId, ModelMap modelMap) {
        userId = EncryptionUtil.decrypt(userId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first (bad) approach would be to allow slash character in url like in the thread below

[Encoded slash (%2F) with Spring RequestMapping path param gives HTTP 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482020/encoded-slash-2f-with-spring-requestmapping-path-param-gives-http-400)

But i think encoding your encryted text using base64 seems a less twisted way.
And base64 encoding is realy fit for this

> Base64 encoding can be helpful when fairly lengthy identifying
>   information is used in an HTTP environment. For example, a database
>   persistence framework for Java objects might use Base64 encoding to
>   encode a relatively large unique id (generally 128-bit UUIDs) into a
>   string for use as an HTTP parameter in HTTP forms or HTTP GET URLs
>
> Quoted from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Encode your encrypted text with the following:

```
String encryptedText = "/O0sJjPUFgRGfND1TpHrkbyCalgY/rSpE8nhJ/wYjYY=";
String encryptedTextAndEncoded = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedText.getBytes()));

try {
        // Using standard Base64 in URL requires encoding of '+', '/' and '=' 
        encryptedTextAndEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(encryptedTextAndEncoded, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

String.format("%s%s", "youtube.com/videos/", encryptedTextAndEncoded);
```

The resulting url will be:

```
youtube.com/videos/L08wc0pqUFVGZ1JHZk5EMVRwSHJrYnlDYWxnWS9yU3BFOG5oSi93WWpZWT0%3D
```

Which is a perfectly valid url

Then, server side, you will decode the string before using it:

```
@GetMapping("/profile/client-users/{userId}")
    public ModelAndView getAccountAccess(
        @PathVariable String userId, ModelMap modelMap) {
        String decoded = new String(java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(userId.getBytes()));
        userId = EncryptionUtil.decrypt(decoded);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer that i'm looking for.