# How to allow encoded slashes in a @SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, tomcat

I would like to use URLs in a path variable using Spring. However, I cannot get the desired behavior without having to [encode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) the URL twice in the client.

In order to describe the problem I will take as reference the [spring rest service tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), I changed the greeting method to use a path variable as follows:

```
    @GetMapping("/greeting/{name}")
    public Greeting greeting(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
```

If try to use the URL `http://localhost:8080/greeting/test/slash` I would get a HTTP 404 NOT_FOUND response. But if I try something like `http://localhost:8080/greeting/test%2Fslash`, I will get a 400 BAD_REQUEST response.

[There is one answer in this question that suggests the use of the ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482020/encoded-slash-2f-with-spring-requestmapping-path-param-gives-http-400), but it does not work. Like changing the property in the `RestServiceApplication` class.

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Ralf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58303792/11748454) seems to address all three issues you'll be facing: Tomcat's security feature, Spring's security feature and Spring's URI path parsing (which decodes the URI before extracting the parameters).

Comment: Yes, I tried that answer and it works. thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[As Piotr pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69408158/how-to-allow-encoded-slashes-in-a-springbootapplication?noredirect=1#comment122690510_69408158), [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58303792/4253946) works as I would expect.

- Allows the encoded slash.
- Does not expand the path variable so I do not get a 404 either.

The solution would be as follow

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestServiceApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
        SpringApplication.run(RestServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setUrlDecode(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```