# How to allow question mark in a URL with spring boot embeded tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, tomcat, hapi-fhir

```
html://www.somewhat.com/_search%3Fname=blabla
```

I have a this type of URL. It works when I replace `%3F` with `?` mark. But I need it to work with both. I have tried with `relaxed-path-chars:"?"` and `relaxed-query-chars:"?"` in application.yaml. But I have found it only works `< > [ \ ] ^  { | }` these symbols.

```
{ "resourceType": "OperationOutcome", "issue": [ { "severity": "error", "code": "not-supported", "diagnostics": "Invalid request: The FHIR endpoint on this server does not know how to handle GET operation[url] with parameters [[]]" } ] }
```

I am using a tomcat embedded spring boot server. What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482020/encoded-slash-2f-with-spring-requestmapping-path-param-gives-http-400

Comment: @Nikhil unfortunately UDecder class only has one static variable "ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH". But I need for question mark. ☹️