# spring-way handle slash in resource name

Tags: java, spring, rest, url

I have following method in controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/items/{identifier}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable String identifier) {
    ... 
    // find item in database by identifier
}
```

The problem is identifier is a **String** that can contain slash **('/')**. I.e. situation can occurs:

```
http://myhost/items/file:/123
```

For given URL 'identifier' must be "file:/123".

And if there is a '/', 405 (method is not allowed) throws due to incorrect URL.

How to tell Spring that it should take all after **'/items/'** as 'identifier' (resource name in REST terms)?

**EDIT:**
I was told that it is client's responsibility to manage slashes and encoding, so I left it as it was.

But for the info, based on [ankur-singhal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231230/ankur-singhal) answer in comments:

Support that I wanted to was added in Spring 4.1.0, see [this link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11401) and this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/426b77b83405b1b4778a96e5dc7075f553d79211).
So in my case it'll be:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/items/{/identifier}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
```

'/' before 'identifier' did a trick.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219/urlencoded-forward-slash-is-breaking-url

Comment: I am testing with JUnit so far, not on real application server.

Comment: @user2138356 try with my answer, if it works for you

Comment: Just a remark : `/` is said *slash*, and `\ ` is said *backslash* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing code to below, see if it works

It will accept any value for `identifier`.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/items/{identifier:.*}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable String identifier) {
    ... 
    // find item in database by identifier
}
```

If you use `identifier` as `request parameter` then you can achieve it as follows :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/items", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@RequestParam("identifier") String identifier) {
    ... 
    // find item in database by identifier
}
```

Please refer [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11401) for more info.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tried this. This solution works with dots, for example, but not with backslashes.

Comment: @user2138356 using `requestParam`..??

Comment: I use {identifier} like resource name not as requestParam.

Comment: @user2138356 here is a [link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11401), and they talk about encoding the url.

Comment: Thank you about link, I found it usefull. Edited my question.

Comment: Move link from comments to answer body. Then I'll accept it as 'solved', thanks!