# urlencode and mod_rewrite slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

i have a problem with urlencode and links. When i have a link that has "/" inside the name of the product let's says my url breaks. I use urlencode and i also have a mod_rewrite for links. Let's say that for nume `$produs['Nume_Prod']` i have a slash inside name my url breaks. For example this link does not work http://onyboutique.ro/Rucsacuri/Rucsac%2fghiozdan%20dama%20negru%20cu%20alb%20Scotti/ . At decode it displays just `ghiozdan dama negru cu alb Scotti` instead `Rucsac/ghiozdan dama negru cu alb Scotti`

```
<a href="/'.urlencode($produs['Nume_Categ']).'/', urlencode($produs['Nume_Prod']), '/" data-id="'.$produs['ID_Produs'].'">Products</a>


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/([^-]*)/$ /detalii_produs.php?cat=$1&nume=$2 [L,B] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Urls with `%2f` or `%5c` return a `404` from Apache for security purposes and your `.htaccess` won't be invoked.

Comment: it does not return 404, it does not decode as it should `Rucsac/ghiozdan dama negru cu alb Scotti`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urlencoded Forward slash is breaking URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219/urlencoded-forward-slash-is-breaking-url)