# ReSTful service getting contradict due to path parameter value has forward slash

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have API like this-

1. `/objectname/name`
2. `/objectname/collection/id`

Both API's are indirectly related.

Problem occurs when calling first API with name value as "A/B Type". So rest controller actually calling second API rather first (`/objectname/A/B Type`) because forward slash. How to deal with this situation.

As a side note I am encoding the parameters values.

I developed the restful services using SpringBoot and RestTemplate.

Comment: Encoding the parameters how?  URL encoding?

Comment: We are already doing, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

The conflict comes by specifying the name directly in the resource path and passed to the function as a @PathVariable.

Your code looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "objectname/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String yourMethodName(@PathVariable String name){
        return name;
    }
```

What I would recommend in order to avoid this kind of conflict is (if you're allowed to modify the @RestController or @RepositoryRestResource layers) to pass the value of the object in a @RequestParam

For instance:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/objectname", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String yourMethodName(@RequestParam(name = "name", required = true) String name){
 return name;
}
```

That said, When you are constructing your the request using RestTemplate then you should url encode your name (A%2FB%20Testing) and construct the following url:

http://localhost:8080/objectname?name=A%2FB%20Testing

I tested this locally and worked alright for me.

Comment: Note: You can take a look at the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219/urlencoded-forward-slash-is-breaking-url

Comment: as alternative to the solution I provided (passing the value as a RequestParam is easier to implement thought)

Comment: i got your point, i cant change API "RequestMapping". Problem is if i already have API request mapping as "/objectName". Is there any other way we can solve it?