# Slashes in GET request (to be used with PHP back end)

Tags: php, get

I have to send a GET request to my Apache server. Whenever the parameters have values that are just one words, things work smoothly. Whenever, there are spaces, I am changing them to `%20` and it does the trick

However, whenever I have slashes in my parameter values, things do not work.
For example, the URL I want to send to my server is:

https://randomness.com?path=/var/images/sub%20images/&name=image%2001.jpg

How can I get a workaround regarding this?

Comment: The error you are getting is? Any code you could share. Your starting your string with a " and ending with a `.

Comment: Have you tried applying the same treatment to the slashes as you did the spaces? Encoding the special characters in your URL might help here. Try using `%2F` rather than `/`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219/urlencoded-forward-slash-is-breaking-url

Answer (score 0):

Many characters are specifically interpreted by the web host in URLs and the `/` character is one of them.

You can translate your `/` characters to `%2F`, like you translate  to `%20`.

PHP's [urlencode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) can also handle these translations for you automatically.

A handy reference for these encodings [can be found here](http://krypted.com/utilities/html-encoding-reference/),
 should you wish to handle it manually.