# URL encoding and decoding in PHP

Tags: php, url

This is a follow up for a previous question I asked yesterday here: [Slashes in GET request (to be used with PHP back end)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057461/slashes-in-get-request-to-be-used-with-php-back-end/44057660#44057660)

I have a link that has 2 GET parameters in it where I want to use in my PHP whenever I visit that website. The link has both `spaces` and `slashes` in it.

Using the amazing answer provided in the previous question, I was able to get the parameters and retrieve them via the get methods as follows:

https://randomness.com?path=%2Fvar%2Fimages%2Fsub%20images%2&name=image%2001.jpg

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

Then I do a merging for the above in the following way:

```
$filePath = "$path" . "$name";
```

then echoying `$filepath`, gives me : `/var/images/sub images/&name=image01.jpg`
and then use it inside my method, `show($filepath);`

Unfortunately, this does not work.
However, if I use the following:

`show('/var/images/sub images/&name=image01.jpg')` 
the method works fine.

To investigate more, whenever I do a comparison using `strcmp` I get that one string is bigger than the other, even though echoyin both shows the same on the screen.

```
strcmp($file_name, '/var/images/sub images/&name=image01.jpg');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `var_dump()` both strings, `echo bin2hex()` both strings, `echo htmlentities()` both strings; wild guess: the `&` in the second string is actually an `&amp;`.

Comment: `%2&` <- are you sure about that? it should be `%2f%26`