# A forward slash from https:// is being removed when sending a /oauth/authorize request to a Rails app from a chrome extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome-extension, oauth, doorkeeper

I am making a launchWebAuthFlow authorization code request from a Chrome extension to a Rails app hosted on Heroku.  Doorkeeper is an OAuth wrapper for Rails, and that is what is processing my request.  More specifically Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController#new is processing the request as HTML (why HTML?).
The forward slash (/) is missing from both the URL encoded redirect_uri and the redirect_uri shown in the rails params. The url is correct on the chrome extension side of things (unless the launchWebAuthFlow built in function is doing something to it), so I think something is happening on the server.
It works in development so I don't think anything is wrong on the extension.  The app is hosted on Heroku.

Any idea of what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235361/5832311), Apache denies all URLs with `%2F` in the path part, for security reasons: scripts can't normally (ie. without rewriting) tell the difference between `%2F` and `/` due to the `PATH_INFO` environment variable being automatically URL-decoded.

> You can turn this feature off using the [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) directive, but note that other web servers will still disallow it (with no option to turn that off), and that other characters may also be taboo (eg. `%5C`), and that `%00` in particular will always be blocked by both Apache and IIS. So if your application relied on being able to have `%2F` or other characters in a path part you'd be limiting your compatibility/deployment options.
>
> You should use [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php), not `urlencode()` for escaping path parts. `urlencode()` is misnamed, it is actually for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data such as in the query string or the body of a POST request, and not for other parts of the URL.
>
> The difference is that `+` doesn't mean space in path parts. `rawurlencode()` will correctly produce `%20` instead, which will work both in form-encoded data and other parts of the URL.

Hope this helps!