# @PathVariable is giving 400 Bad Request

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am using path variable and when i hit the request i get 400 BAD Request

URL :  http://localhost:8085/testing/v3/w200/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bildarchivaustria.at%2FPreview%2F15620341.jpg

I don't know why it's not working. It might be something very simple that i am missing. Please help

Here is my code :

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/testing/v3")
public class ControllerV3 
{
@GetMapping(value = "/{size}/{url}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> testByUrl(
            @PathVariable(name="size", value="size" , required = false) String size,
            @PathVariable("url") String url,
            WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletResponse response) {
        long startTime = 0;
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            LOG.debug("url = {}, size = {}", url, size);
        }
// i do other process here and return the image or video
}
}
```

Comment: How should this be compilable, you don't even return something in your method.

Comment: I could image that have an optional `PathVariable` as the first one is also a bad idea

Comment: I also never heard of a `404 BAD Request` i would expect a 404 not found, could you provide some logging maybe a stacktrace?

Comment: Hello all, 404 bad request because somehow it is not able to identify this URL. Ia m sorry there is no stacktrace generated as well. I do return something and have a long process. But First it should identify the URL to proceed

Comment: 404 is "not found", bad request is "400"

Comment: Sorry my bad , 400 Bad Request

Comment: @MartinvanWingerden even when i remove the optional, i am getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons Apache does not allow any `%2F`as part of the path [(find out more here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235361/3493036).

To get the stuff working replace all `%2F` with `%252F` in your URL:

```
http://localhost:8085/testing/v3/w200/http%3A%252F%252Flocalhost%3A8080%252Ftesting%252Fv3%252Fw200%252Fhttp%3A%252F%252Fwww.bildarchivaustria.at%252FPreview%252F15620341.jpg
```

> The encoding of `%2F` is -> `%252F`